# Get Controller's Action name in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, action

What is the correct way to get the name of the Action returning the View in MVC3?

I am using `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue` to return the name of the Action (Method), which is creating the View in MVC3. I return this in a Partial View, which is included in the View returned by the Action.

It works fine for Index, but, when I try to use it for another method name, it always evaluates to false.

In the immediate window I get the following results:

```
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
"Edit"

ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue == "Edit"
false
```

Which is highly confusing, because the first statement evaluates to a string with value "Edit", while comparing this to a string "Edit" returns false?

Bizarre...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`RawValue` is an `object`, so `RawValue == "..."` calls `Object.op_Equality`, which comparse by reference rather than by value.

Call `ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")`

Comment: Thanks but this returns `RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Routing.RequestContext.RouteData.get'
`

Comment: I used this to get a page to link to itself in a generic fashion: 
    @Url.Action(
        ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"), 
        ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")
    )

Comment: @Ceekay: Just use `Request.Url`.